# Cannot cross-compile SDL2 with Mingw-w64 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, cross-compilation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mingw

[SDL downloads](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php#source)

I am on Ubuntu using WSL2 and I want to create an executable that will run on Windows. Currently I can build executables for linux just fine. I downloaded the SDL MinGw windows development tools (link above) to my /opt folder. When I execute `make cross`, I receive this output:

```
for arch in i686-w64-mingw32 x86_64-w64-mingw32; do \
    make install-package arch=$arch prefix=/usr/local/$arch; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/SDL2-2.0.12'
*** ERROR: i686-w64-mingw32 or /usr/local/i686-w64-mingw32 does not exist!
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21: install-package] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/SDL2-2.0.12'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/SDL2-2.0.12'
*** ERROR: x86_64-w64-mingw32 or /usr/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32 does not exist!
make[1]: *** [Makefile:21: install-package] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/SDL2-2.0.12'
make: *** [Makefile:16: cross] Error 2
```

If I search for those I get

```
 which i686-w64-mingw32-g++
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++

which x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
```

/usr/bin is on my path and I see executables with those names in the `/opt/SDL2-2.0.12` folder.

The genesis of this is when I try to compile my SDL program with x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ instead of g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the prefix directories:

```
mkdir /usr/local/{i686,x86_64}-w64-mingw32
```

Comment: Thanks, I really missed the mark reading that error message!